# D3 graph causing "Oh Snap"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing a d3 chart that updates every second.

After leaving the tab opened in the background for a while get the "Oh Snap" error on the browser.

I have tracked down the issue to the axis of the chart that dynamically updates depending on the current limits of the data I am receiving (Minimum an Maximum).

CHART FUNCTION:

```
    function realtimeChart($chartContainer, width, height) {
          // data arrays
          this.dataMin = [];
          this.dataMax = [];

          // chart dimensions
          this.width = width || 500;
          this.height = height || 500;

          //
          this.globalX = 0;
          this.duration = 100;
          this.max = 50;
          this.step = 1;

          //
          this.chart = d3.select($chartContainer.get(0))
            .attr('width', this.width)
            .attr('height', this.height + 25);

          var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, this.width])
            .range([40, this.width]),
            y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 10])
            .range([this.height - 20, 10]);

          this.line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) {
              return x(d.x);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
              return y(d.y);
            });
          this.smoothLine = d3.line()
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal)
            .x(function(d) {
              return x(d.x);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
              return y(d.y);
            });
          this.lineArea = d3.area()
            .x(function(d) {
              return x(d.x);
            })
            .y0(y(0))
            .y1(function(d) {
              return y(d.y);
            })
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

          // Draw the axis
          this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
          this.yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);

          this.axisX = this.chart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (this.height - 20) + ')')
            .call(this.xAxis);

          this.axisY = this.chart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(40, 0)')
            .call(this.yAxis);

          // Append the holder for line chart and fill area
          this.pathMin = this.chart.append('path');
          this.pathMax = this.chart.append('path');

          this.next = function(min, max) {
            // Generate new data
            var pointMin = {
                x: this.globalX,
                y: min || 0
              },
              pointMax = {
                x: this.globalX,
                y: max || cur
              };

            this.dataMin.push(pointMin);
            this.dataMax.push(pointMax);

            this.globalX += this.step;

            // Shift the chart left
            x.domain([this.globalX - (this.max - this.step) - 1, this.globalX - 1]);
            y.domain([min - 2, max + 2]);

            //THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED WHEN I COMMENT THE AXIS UPDATE
            this.axisX.transition()
              .duration(this.duration)
              .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
              .call(this.xAxis);
            this.axisY.transition()
              .duration(this.duration)
              .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
              .call(this.yAxis);

            // Draw new line
            this.pathMin.datum(this.dataMin)
              .attr('class', 'smoothline min')
              .attr('d', this.smoothLine);

            this.pathMax.datum(this.dataMax)
              .attr('class', 'smoothline max')
              .attr('d', this.smoothLine);

            // Remote old data (max 49 pointCurs)
            if (this.dataCur.length > 49) {
              this.dataMin.shift();
              this.dataMax.shift();
            }
          }
      }
```

HOW I AM INITIALIZING THE CHART:

```
    var $chartDiv;
    $chartDiv = $("<div>")
      .addClass("timerRow")
      .addClass("chartRow")
      .append(function() {
        var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
          return $(svg)
            .attr({
              "width": "500",
              "height": "500",
              "class": "chart"
            });
       });

    $chartDiv.data({
      "chart": new realtimeChart(
            $chartDiv.find("svg").first(),
            $("#dataDiv").innerWidth() - 40,
          150)
    })
```

HOW I UPDATE THE CHART AFTER RECIEVING NEW DATA:

```
  chart = $chartRow.data("chart")
  chart.next(timeData.min, timeData.max);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue without removing the axis?

Comment: Could you post a functional example/ snippet?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I added the full code on my original post, keep in mind that this chart is repeated like 20 times on the same page for different parameters. So maybe you won't have the same issue just by trying it with a single chart.

Comment: Code snippet would really help. Code seems to be missing, for example, where is `this.next` called?

Comment: I tried to add a simplified version to an online console but failed to make it work.
I updated my initial post with the code where I draw the graph and with the lines in which I use `this.next`, I hope it's clearer now.
The problem is when I am updating the axis so maybe if anyone has a suggestion on how I could do that differently that could solve the issue.